# See document in list without opening it in SP2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions

is it possible in Sharepoint 2010 set a permission on a document in order to allow a specific user to view this document (when viewing the documents of a specific document library for example) without giving him the privilege to open it?

For example, [user1] can see that in the list of documents of document library [DocLib1]  there is a document called [doc1.docx], but [user1] doesn't have the permission to open[doc1.docx] and view its content.

Answer (score 2):

Technically raymund's answer is obscurity instead of security. If you are going to go that route you can simply update your primary view to remove any links to the document. and create a seperate view for those authorized.

Edit***

after double checking msdn, I found the user permissions article. This shows that there are in deed two seperate permission levels - view items and open items. unfortunately view items is dependent upon the open items permission level, therefore unable to really accomplish your goal.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx

Comment: Do you think there might be a custom solution or a workaround?

Comment: the easiest solution would be to maintain a separate list that contains a list of the files, and use this list to display the information. You could then provide security on the actual document library. 

I guess a better question would be as to why someone would be able to see a document they can't open.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a SOAP Service Connection in Sharepoint Designer

[image]

Then using your Document List as the source (declaring a login on the login tab with a privilage to tread the list) , then displaying it as a dataview in a sharpoint form.

[image]

I have a similar sample [here](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/displaying-a-sharepoint-list-from-another-team-site-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010/) which has a better explanation using a list instead (I should work the same with document library as they are exposed both as lists).